# Error trying to connect to Joomla database: jtablesession::Store Failed DB function failed with error number 1146

Tags: database, joomla

I have my current website I'm wanting to replace.

I've created a subdomain development website I want to replace current site with.

I've backed up everything, created a new database in the control panel for current website.

I then exported the database from the development site via phpMyAdmin.

Next I uploaded the database sql data into the new database I created in the control panel.

Once all this was completed, I updated the configuration file for apprhs.org to connect to the new database. After I do this, I receive the following error message when trying to access the website:

jtablesession::Store Failed DB function failed with error number 1146 Table '632056_newSite.jos_session' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_session` ( `session_id`,`time`,`username`,`gid`,`guest`,`client_id` ) VALUES ( 'dvv0sr2snsff3qvo8bu0j9ljp0','1449724899','','0','1','0' )

The current website is running Joomla 1.5 and the development site is running joomla 3.4. Could this cause any issues?

Answer (score 0):

Create table jos_session in your database:

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_session` (
`username` varchar(150) default '',
`time` varchar(14) default '',
`session_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
`guest` tinyint(4) default '1',
`userid` int(11) default '0',
`usertype` varchar(50) default '',
`gid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`client_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`data` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`(64)),
KEY `whosonline` (`guest`,`usertype`),
KEY `userid` (`userid`),
KEY `time` (`time`)
) TYPE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET `utf8`;
```

**Update:**
For mysql 5.0 >:

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_session` (
`username` varchar(150) default '',
`time` varchar(14) default '',
`session_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
`guest` tinyint(4) default '1',
`userid` int(11) default '0',
`usertype` varchar(50) default '',
`gid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`client_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`data` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`(64)),
KEY `whosonline` (`guest`,`usertype`),
KEY `userid` (`userid`),
KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET `utf8`;
```

Comment: Do I add that via myphpadmin?

Comment: I received the following error when trying to create this:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET `utf8`' at line 15

Comment: I added this to my DB and now get this error when trying to access site:


jtablesession::Store Failed
DB function failed with error number 1054
Unknown column 'gid' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO `oqn8s_session` ( `session_id`,`time`,`username`,`gid`,`guest`,`client_id` ) VALUES ( 'q4vo5junededamooejju11f5m3','1449763922','','0','1','0' )

Comment: Change query, replace table name to oqn8s_session :
CREATE TABLE `oqn8s_session` (
`username` varchar(150) default '',
`time` varchar(14) default '',
`session_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
`guest` tinyint(4) default '1',
`userid` int(11) default '0',
`usertype` varchar(50) default '',
`gid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`client_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`data` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`(64)),
KEY `whosonline` (`guest`,`usertype`),
KEY `userid` (`userid`),
KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET `utf8`;

Comment: 404 error is not subject truble. 404 is http status code - document not found

Answer (score 0):

`DROP table IF EXISTS jos_session;
CREATE TABLE`jos_session`(`
username`varchar(150) default '',`
time`varchar(14) default '',`
session_id`varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',`
guest`tinyint(4) default '1',`
userid`int(11) default '0',`
usertype`varchar(50) default '',`
gid`tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`(64)),
KEY`whosonline`(`guest`,`usertype`),
KEY`userid`(`userid`),
KEY`time`(`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`